# What causes svn error 413 Request Entity Too Large?

Tags: svn

On occasion I receive an error "413 Request Entity Too Large" while updating an svn repository. Once I receive this error, it continues every time I attempt to update the local working copy. A new checkout will solve the problem, but is very inconvenient. The project is over 30 GB, and the SVN repository is hosted externally.

This has occurred in the past on several different computers, including Windows development machines, and our Linux build server.

Most of what I have found regarding this issue relates to large individual files (over 2GB). This is not the case here, as the largest files are approx. 50-60 MB.

Has anyone else ran into this before and/or know the cause/solution to this?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try to add the following configuration directives to your Apache configuration file:

```
LimitXMLRequestBody 8000000
LimitRequestBody 0
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much. I've been having this exact problem too. Your answer solved it neatly.

Comment: That worked an absolute treat, but do you know what the logic behind this is?

Comment: @RobForrest By default Apache server limit request body size to prevent DoS attacks. Subversion reports status of working to server using XML request body and then server sends updates to this working copy. Default limit is 1mb, which is fine for most setups but sometimes for big working copies it's not enough.

Comment: Great! it was the solution for my problem, thanks @ivan-zhakov

Comment: Considering that the default values for those are set to help to curb/avoid DDoS attacks, is it 'safe' to lower them to 0? Is there another value they could be set to so they are still providing some 'protection'?

Comment: @FelipeAlvarez: Thanks for reminder. It's almost safe to lower LimitRequestBody to 0 or some really large value like 100-1000MB, but it's unsafe to have large or unlimited (0) value for LimitXMLRequestBody, because it stored in memory. From my testing 8000000 for LimitXMLRequestBody is enough for all Subversion cases. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 46):

I don't have access to my repo server (IT Managed, and its over the weekend).  So what I found was that I could work around this issue by doing an svn update on subdirs until one wouldn't work.
Then I descended into this dir until I stopped getting the 413 error.  Then I could do an update at higher levels.
Might not work for everyone but could help get through in an emergency

Comment: That's a good suggestion. You can start at the top level doing "svn up *" - if that fails on a subdir just decidend into it and repeat. If you have a subdir with lots of folders, just doing "svn up *" on that may be enough to fix the problem.

Comment: Arr... the reason I'm trying to get us to switch to Git. Less of this funny business.

Comment: occured again for me. I just ran "svn up *" at the top level as per Jan's suggestion and it somehow sorted it self out.

Comment: And when you find that manually running through all the directories gets to be too tedious: `find -type d | grep -v -e "\.svn" | tac | xargs -d"\n" -n1 svn up`

Answer (score 7):

Made a short bash script to loop through the subdirectories, per mdh's answer:

```
for dir in *; do
    [[ -e $dir ]] || continue
    echo "Updating $dir"
    svn up $dir
done
svn up
```

Comment: You don't want to parse ls: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs
Instead, you should consider using find or bash globbing.

Comment: Fair point, thanks. Updated to use bash instead. Also now logging the directory which failed so it can be dealt with

Comment: Don't know why this is voted down. If you have no access to the server then this is the only thing you can do to get around the problem.

Comment: Very very very good!!! Thanks a lot, man! This is the right answer for ones that don't have access to server.

Comment: This worked, thanks!  (People who have spaces in their directory names will need to change 'svn up $dir' to 'svn up "$dir" '.)

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue recently with any file over 10MB.  It turns out I forgot I'm proxying the svn/apache server with nginx.  Changing `client_max_body_size` in `nginx.conf` fixed the issue. I left `LimitXMLRequestBody` and `LimitRequestBody` on the Apache server at their defaults.

Answer (score 2):

If without access to the server, you can also select all the folders using ctrl+A and then right click to update all folders individually using tortoise svn etc. Essentially the same as @lucrussell's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you run mod_security, consider checking your SecRequestBodyLimit setting.  Mine was set too low and was causing the problem.