# svn up and "413 Request Entity Too Large"

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm having troubles with cheking out a folder from a repository (it's some of 23 GB if that matters). First I had problems with connection failure:

> Could not read response body: Secure connection truncated

To solve it, each time after failure I tried to do cleanup and update after that. That helped, but then I started to get the error

> Server sent unexpected return value (413 Request Entity Too Large) in
>   response

Can someone tell me how can I fix this?

The reason why I'm asking the question is that I'm using http and not https, so no problem with a certificate is possible.

I'm using the TortoiseSVN client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution.

This is a repository ownership problem. To change ownership:

```
chown -R apache:apache {repo} or
chmod -R www-data:www-data {repo).
```

That's it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using NGINGX with proxy to Apache, then you need to set something like `client_max_body_size 4G;` in your `nginx.conf`.

Comment: thanks so much :) did the trick for the nginx apache proxy setup

Answer (score 2):

I found something like this:

```
LimitXMLRequestBody 0
LimitRequestBody 0
```

The problem "413 Request Entity Too Large" was fixed

More hire: [What causes svn error 413 Request Entity Too Large?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976868/what-causes-svn-error-413-request-entity-too-large)