# svn up error 413 -- tried every option I could find

Tags: apache, svn, centos

I am getting the svn  error "413 Request Entity Too Large" while using svn up  and none of the answers on Stackoverflow or anywhere else solved the problem.
 I've added in theLimitXMLRequestBody 0
LimitRequestBody 0 into my httpd.conf per the other [svn error 413 question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976868/what-causes-svn-error-413-request-entity-too-large). I even tried putting LimitRequestBody allowing ten terrabytes of data as the maximum.  I don't have SSL being used and sslverifyclient was already commented out in my ssl.conf, so it isn't the bug discussed on haxx.se. Now that I've ruled all of these possibilities out, I am stumped.

Is it possible that the remote server is rejecting my request because it is too big? I am getting gigabytes of data via  svn, but I didn't have a problem until I started using svn up. I've been stuck with this issue for a couple weeks before I decided to ask. Any help is helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is svn up and then select specific folders like svn up myproject or svn up my*, which will update anything that starts with my. My is just an example of a word you can use. You can use any character you want.