# Totoise SVN Error "413 Request Entity Too Large"

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm a window user. To keep my data, I use Tortoise SVN 1.7.12.

At the time of commiting my file, I found the error "413 Request Entity Too Large".

I don't want to separate my file.

How can solve this problem?

Comment: I guess you're using svn over http, so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976868/what-causes-svn-error-413-request-entity-too-large might answer your question. If possible, consider using the svn protocol directly.

Comment: @Arkanosis ⇒ I saw your reference link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976868/what-causes-svn-error-413-request-entity-too-large#comment15795028_9053059). But I don't know location of Apache Configuration file. please help me.

Comment: Why do you still use the old 1.7 instead of 1.8?

Comment: @ magicandre1981 ⇒ what is the difference between 1.7 and 1.8?