# SVN Error: Unexpected HTTP status 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: apache, svn

Trying to check out a repository and I am getting this error on one specific client machine. I even tried another smaller repository and got the same thing.

I tried the answers here with no luck:
[What causes svn error 413 Request Entity Too Large?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976868/what-causes-svn-error-413-request-entity-too-large)

The odd part is that the answers in that question seem to be focused on server settings, and I can connect to the same server and check out the same repository from other clients without issue.

What are some other things to look for?

The client in question is running Windows Server 2008 R2, I've tried with Tortoise and SlikSvn command line client both with the same result.

The svn server is a regular apache configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out. In my case it was due to a Cyberoam router that was filtering HTTP traffic. The traffic itself was being accepted through the filter, but the addition of a Via: header on the request was causing svn to fail.

I had to add a firewall rule to bypass the filter altogether for my svn traffic.